# Payu checksum Error Solution

Tags: php, payu

## Checksum Error

How to solve checksum error I am integrating in php but Checksum error is occured 
How to solve checksum error I am integrating in php but Checksum error is occured

How to solve checksum error

```
/* @ Check User Session : */
 $session_user_id  = $_SESSION[SITE_CODE]['user']['user_id'];

if(!empty($_SESSION['fund']))
{   
    //variable billing details:
    $fname = $_SESSION['fund']['fname'];
    $email = $_SESSION['fund']['email'];
    $mbl = $_SESSION['fund']['mobno'];
    $amount = $_SESSION['fund']['amount'];
    $comment = $_SESSION['fund']['comment'];

    //total payment amount:
    $amount = number_format($_SESSION['fund']['amount'],2,'.','');


/* @ Get Product Details */
     $array['productinfo'] = array("name"=>'AAA',
                                   "description"=>'AAA',
                                   "value"=>$amount,
                                   "isRequired"=>"false");
    $product_info = json_encode($array['productinfo']); 


/**************[Start :: Payment Setup]***********************/

// Merchant key here as provided by Payu
$MERCHANT_KEY = "JBZaLc";

// Merchant Salt as provided by Payu
$SALT = "GQs7yium";

// End point - change to https://secure.payu.in for LIVE mode
$PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://test.payu.in";
$action = '';

$posted = array();
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    //print_r($_POST);
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {    
    $posted[$key] = $value; 
  }
}

$formError = 0;

if(empty($posted['txnid'])) {
  // Generate random transaction id
  $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
} else {
  $txnid = $posted['txnid'];
}

$hash = '';
// Hash Sequence
$hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";
if(empty($posted['hash']) && sizeof($posted) > 0) {
  if(
          empty($posted['key'])
          || empty($posted['txnid'])
          || empty($posted['amount'])
          || empty($posted['firstname'])
          || empty($posted['email'])
          || empty($posted['phone'])
          || empty($posted['productinfo'])
          || empty($posted['surl'])
          || empty($posted['furl'])
          || empty($posted['service_provider'])
  ) {
    $formError = 1;
  } else {

json_encode(json_decode('[{"name":"tutionfee","description":"","value":"500","isRequired":"false"},{"name":"developmentfee","description":"monthly tution fee","value":"1500","isRequired":"false"}]'));
    $hashVarsSeq = explode('|', $hashSequence);
    $hash_string = '';  
    foreach($_SESSION['fund'] as $hash_var) {
      $hash_string .= isset($posted[$hash_var]) ? $posted[$hash_var] : '';
      $hash_string .= '|';
    }

    $hash_string .= $SALT;

    $hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hash_string));
    $action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
  }
} elseif(!empty($posted['hash'])) {
  $hash = $posted['hash'];
  $action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
}
/**************[End :: Payment Setup]***********************/
?>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>PayUMoney - Subscription Payment</title>
  <script>
    var hash = '2'; //'<?php //echo $hash ?>';
 operation;
    function submitPayuForm() {
      if(hash == '') {
        return;
      }
      var payuForm = document.forms.payuForm;
      payuForm.submit();
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="submitPayuForm()">
  <center>
    <h2><img src="<?php echo SITE_PATH;?>media/images/payu_india.jpg"></h2>
    <br/>
    <span style="color:black"><strong>Please don't referesh the page ! We are redirecting you on payment process ...</strong></span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h2><img src="<?php echo SITE_PATH;?>media/images/loader1.gif" width="400"></h2> 
    <!--< /?php if($formError) { ?>
      <span style="color:red">Please fill all mandatory fields.</span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
    < ?php } ?>-->

    <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" name="payuForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $MERCHANT_KEY;?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $hash;?>"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="<?php echo $txnid;?>" />
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><!--<b>Mandatory Parameters</b>--></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><!--Amount:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount;?>" /></td>
          <td><!--First Name:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><!--Email:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /></td>
          <td><!--Phone:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<?php echo $mbl; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><!--Product Info:--> </td>
          <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value="<?php echo $product_info; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><!--Success URI:--> </td>
          <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="surl" value="<?php echo SITE_PATH;?>payu-money-success" size="64" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><!--Failure URI:--> </td>
          <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="furl" value="<?php echo SITE_PATH;?>payu-money-failure" size="64" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><!--Service Provider:--> </td>
          <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="<?php echo 'payu_paisa';?>" size="64" /></td>
        </tr>

        <!--<tr>
          <td><b>Optional Parameters</b></td>
        </tr>-->
        <tr>
          <td><!--Last Name:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>" /></td>
          <td><!--Cancel URI:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="curl" value="<?php echo SITE_PATH;?>payu-money-cancel" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><!--Address1:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="address1" value="<?php echo $address; ?>" /></td>
          <td><!--Address2:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="address2" value="<?php echo $address2; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><!--City:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" /></td>
          <td><!--State:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden"name="state" value="<?php echo $state; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><!--Country:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="country" value="<?php echo $country; ?>" /></td>
          <td><!--Zipcode:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="zipcode" value="<?php echo $zipcode; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><!--UDF1:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="udf1" value="<?php echo "camera vintage shopping cart -".date('dmY'); ?>" /></td>
          <td><!--UDF2:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="udf2" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf2'])) ? '' : $posted['udf2']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><!--UDF3:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="udf3" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf3'])) ? '' : $posted['udf3']; ?>" /></td>
          <td><!--UDF4:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="udf4" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf4'])) ? '' : $posted['udf4']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><!--UDF5:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="udf5" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['udf5'])) ? '' : $posted['udf5']; ?>" /></td>
          <td><!--PG:--> </td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="pg" value="<?php echo (empty($posted['pg'])) ? '' : $posted['pg']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <!-- < /?php //if(!$hash) { ?>
            <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
          < /?php //} ?>-->
          <input type="hidden" name="service_button_submit" id="service_button_submit" value="Subscription Confirmed" />
          <input type="hidden" name="make_payment_amount" id="make_payment_amount" value="<?php echo $paper_total_fee;?>" />

        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can anyone help for this issue..

Comment: are you able to resolve this?

Comment: Hey i know this is an old thread. But would be great to know if this was resolved. I am wondering if it is due to the Merchant Key and SALT being only demo values (if they are...since this code is taken from the a sample code online)

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the following things are done.Go step by step and check if it helps.

- Include all udf field while creating hash even if empty.

  $hash_string = $MERCHANT_KEY.'|'.$txnid.'|'.$amount.'|'.$productinfo.'|'.$firstname.'|'.$email.'|||||||||||';
- Ensure there are no spelling mistakes in the string and in the form
  inputs.
- Ensure that the form elements used are not text areas. Just inputs
  will do.
- Re-arrange all the form fields in the same order as the key in the
  documentation.

Hope it helps